# wifi connection work proper still give error that internet connection not available

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, cellular-network, wifi

I want to do code, whether my iPhone is connected with Internet, either wifi or Cellular network.

now my problem is when I execute my application through cellular connection i am not getting any error and application running and web service call working properly but as i switch Internet connection from cellular network to the wifi network i got alert that "No Internet Connection" even if intetnet working properly over wifi.

Can you guys help me to find this problem ?

Code :

In viewDidLoad() i am calling this function :

```
callWSForGetProjectLeadersList()
```

In below function i am checking Internet connection is available or not: isConnectedToNetwork()

```
func callWSForGetProjectLeadersList()
{
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
    {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
            do
            {
                try WebServiceCall.webServiceCall("getUsers", parameters: nil, tag: "getUsers", reference: self, type: "POST")
            }
            catch
            {
                CommonFunctions.exceptionAlert()
                return
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO : This is part should not run while Internet connection is avail.
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            Toast.showMessage(self.view, msg: "Please check your internet connection and try after sometime", time: 2.0)
        })
    }
}
```

now in below class code having ToCheck Internet connection :

```
public class Reachability {

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    /* Only Working for WIFI
     let isReachable = flags == .reachable
     let needsConnection = flags == .connectionRequired

     return isReachable && !needsConnection
     */

    // Working for Cellular and WIFI
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)

    return ret

}
```

when i run it over wifi it call below function :

```
class func networkAlert()
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet!", message: "No working Internet connection is Found.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
        alert.show()
    })
}
```

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani bro It's perfectly run in Mobile Data... Issue accrue in wifi network

Comment: Have you set some proxy in your Wifi settings?